# pop shows the scrollbar(vertical)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i m working with wordpress in bootstrap theme. my problem is that i opened a popup on my home page and its working fine in mozila but in chrome it shows vertical scrollbar.plzzzz guys help me.

here is my code for popup div:

```
<div id="openHouse" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="overflow-y:hidden">
  <div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close well" data-dismiss="modal">×</button><br />
    <a href="http://pearlacademy.com/open-house/"><img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Open-House-2.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>​
```

and jquery file:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#openHouse').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the plugin you use for the modal dialog? Can you make a test case we can poke around in? (jsbin.com, jsfiddle.net, etc). You can always use the jQuery UI's dialog plugin, it supports modal, works well, and has a lot of examples available.

Comment: i m using Modal Dialog plugin for it

Comment: sorry dude..i m using this code from bootstrap theme to open a modal popup . i just want to know that how can i give the height and widthto the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont know what jquery plugin you are using, you can add width and height via css. Thanks